# A connected set which is a subset of a union of two separated sets, must be is in one of them not both.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if a connected set in a metric space which is a subset of a union of two separated sets, must be is in just  them.

Namely, suppose $C$ is a connected set in a metric space (M,d). Let $U$ and $V$ be two separated sets in $(M,d)$ such that $C \subseteq U \cup V$. Show that $C \subseteq U$ or $C \subseteq U$.

I know I should use the following:

Let $A= C \cap U$, $B= C \cap V$

Since $\bar{A} \subseteq \bar{C} \cup \bar{U} \subseteq \bar{U} \rightarrow \bar{A} \subseteq \bar{U}$

Also, Since $\bar{B} \subseteq \bar{C} \cup \bar{V} \subseteq \bar{V} \rightarrow \bar{B} \subseteq \bar{V}$

and assume that if both are nonempty what happens? But I can go further?

$\textbf{Please try to complete my answer not proposing different method?}$

Comment: I recommend you start a bounty for this question. I am unsure on how to answer, but I am interested in the result and believe it deserves more attention :).